# Знаки препинания вместо союза "что"

Tags: тире-или-двоеточие

Какой знак препинания следует ставить на месте вопроса? Двоеточие?

– А говоришь (?) мудрец, – вздохнул он. – Это я и без тебя знаю…

Comment: Татьяна, посмотрите в тексте вопроса: *А с другой стороны, может быть, и стоит съездить, осмотреться… вернуться-то ты всегда успеешь…*  К чему относится это предложение?

Comment: Запятую надо, хотя и тире можно "говоришь - (что он) мудрец"

Comment: Буратино, спасибо! А почему не двоеточие? Я запуталась в структуре... Вторая часть - неполное? Тире на месте пропуска подлежащего?

Comment: Римма, я удалила это предложение.

Comment: @Татьяна мне кажется, что можно рассуждать, что неполное. Ну можно выдумать, чтобы тире поставить: "Как ты там говоришь про своего начальника: " он - мудрец.." - вот и я говорю также про своего. То есть двоеточие может быть связано с оформлением чего-то не относящегося напрямую ко второй части, то что внутри двоеточия, относится только к тому, что до двоеточия. А тут вроде и говоришь и мудрец относятся ко второй части равноправно. Двоеточие - это как коробка, матрешка, а в ней еще, но смысловые связки идут через часть вне двоеточия, не касаясь содержания внутри. А тире - это повороты,пропуски.

Comment: @Татьяна но это мои фантазии, я это только что выдумал!)

Comment: @Буратино Это очень интересно, спасибо ))

Comment: @Татьяна там оговорка: чтобы *двоеточие* поставит, а не *тире*. Думаю одно, пишу другое, как с этим справиться? Точнее думаю сразу о двух вещах, а пишу то, о чем стараюсь не думать)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147376/discussion-between--and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*– **А говоришь, мудрец**, – вздохнул он. – Это я и без тебя знаю…*

Сравним с СПП с придаточным изъяснительным: *А говоришь, **что мудрец**.*

Но у нас БСП: ***А говоришь, мудрец.***  Или: ***А говоришь – мудрец***.  Интонация вариантов похожая, только паузы разные по длительности.

***А говоришь: мудрец.*** При двоеточии пауза выглядит неоправданно **"затянутой"** для такой структуры предложения и всего текста.

Comment: Поняла. Я и оценивала его как БСП. Почему-то уверена, что в БСП, если можно подставить союз "что", то двоеточие всегда ставится, как в учебниках написано. Буду иметь в виду, что можно и так ).

Comment: Тут вот что интересно. Подстановка союза «что» используется для проверки изъяснительного значения  БСП. Проверив, мы выбираем нужный знак в БСП: (1) классическое двоеточие, (2) тире как его замена и  (3) запятая при отсутствии интонационного предупреждения, характерного для двоеточия.
Подстановки в общем случае – это методика анализа, но не критерий ответа. А по учебнику кажется, что именно ответ.

Comment: Да, поняла, спасибо! Я, видимо, невнимательно, отношусь к теории. А где о замене можно почитать? У Розенталя?

Comment: Я использую учебник по грамматике для вузов: Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций. У меня 2013 год, можно купить электронную версию 2018 года. Там есть все темы. Уровень сложности доступный, его можно использовать как справочник.  В книге говорится о виде отношений (изъяснительные).  Но такие отношения возможны в СПП и БСП. Вот и делаем соответствующие выводы. С помощью этой книги можно постепенно приобрести "системное образование" в грамматике и свободно ориентироваться в ней.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Приобрету обязательно!

Comment: Посмотрите сначала издание 2005 года, там много общего, но и различия есть. Некоторые разделы были дополнены.  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf